# Ipad, using safari went to a porn site and now same flashing message keeps jumping up and down and cannot close out

Tags: ipad

Went to a porn site using safari and suddenly a flashing message came to the screen, Big mistake on my part but can it be fixed. 
Two messages one says Print option and goes up the screen then down to disappear then up again like a jumping jack. The screen behind says at Top safari-securityalert.com and the actual screen says "Contact Support and gives a Telephone number Support  1 844 749-1071.  Also says my "iPad has been locked due to detected illegal activity. Call Immediately and says call Apple Support to unlock".  I very much doubt this is an Apple telephone number.      .
I have not been able to exit the site as it keeps flashing and jumping and no matter how many times I hit the X, nothing happens. I have rebooted twice. Can this be a virus or malware from going to a Safari site? What to do to remedy. 
Is this a virus? How can I get out of this cycle of jumping jack message?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a popup that appears every time you launch a page. Here's how you can get rid of it:

1. Force close Safari.
2. Turn off Wi-Fi (and cell service, if you have it).
3. Reopen Safari and, since the page can't load, you won't get the popup.
4. Close the tab that gave you the popup.
5. Turn Wi-Fi (and cell service) back on.

Good luck!